# Enabling DHL Marketplace in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, magento2.2, dhl

How can I add [DHL Market Place](https://marketplace.magento.com/dhl-module-shipping-m2.html) in my Magento 2 admin? Been searching on how to enable it but can't find any solution. Should I just copy the download file into the `app` folder? or do I need to go to the admin panel?

Note: Beginner here

Answer (score 0):

Ok for those who will be encountering the same issue as I have here is the answer and I'm referring this to the answer that the developer gave me.

If you are running in PHP 7+ and want to install via VCS then  below are the command you need to run and `DON'T` use installation that they provided in the README.md specially for version 0.10.0. It lacks the proper instruction on how to install it in Magento 2.3 using version 0.10.0 Below are the correct command needed to run and install DHL in your Magento project

```
composer config repositories.dhl-shipping-m2 vcs git@github.com:netresearch/dhl-module-shipping-m2.git <-- This is the important part to make it work

composer require dhl/module-shipping-m2:0.10.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Magento2 follows a structure to add custom modules .. Their are two ways to add extensions in m2..

1 : Install it from the composer  Eg: for DHL to install from composer

composer require dhl/module-shipping-m2:0.10.0

It will directly saved in vendor folder

2 : Manual installation , Download the extension and copy that into the magento root ie.. app/code/yourextension

Comment: Yeah tried that specially the number 1 suggestion but if you try this with PHP 7.2+ you will get an error saying that it cannot install due to PHP version issue. Eventhough you have 7+ php version its still giving an error

Also putting it in the APP folder will throw an error and is not advisable to put it there and there is nowhere in the installation/readme.md that says you need to place the code in the app folder